# Calculating $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\lambda}|_{\lambda=0}$ for $\phi(x+\lambda a)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

My function is $\phi(x+\lambda a)$, where $x$ and $\lambda$ are variables and $a$ is a constant. I want to calculate what $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\lambda}$ is.

Let's define $u=x+\lambda a$ so $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\lambda} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\lambda} = a\frac{d\phi}{d u}$

But now I somehow want to change back to an expression in terms of $x$ and $\lambda$.

I do know that $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\lambda}|_{\lambda=0} = a \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}$ but I can't figure out the general expression for any given $\lambda$

Comment: On the RHS of your computation for $\partial_{\lambda} \phi$ it should be $\phi'(u) = d \phi/d u$, not $\partial_{u} \phi$. Then, evaluating both sides at $\lambda = 0$, we have $u = x$ and hence $\partial_{\lambda} \phi = a \phi'(x)$.

Comment: I see the point of the partial, but setting $\lambda = 0$ before taking the derivative doesn't seem right. Could I not find a general expression for any $\lambda$?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. We didn't set $\lambda = 0$ before taking the derivative. We took the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ to get $\partial_{\lambda} \phi = a \phi'(u)$ and only then did we evaluate both sides at $\lambda = 0$ to get $\partial_{\lambda} \phi \lvert_{\lambda = 0} = a \phi'(x)$.

Comment: Why do you need to go further than $a\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}u}$? If you know $\phi$, then just calculate $\phi'(u)$ and then sub $u=x+\lambda a$ back in.

Comment: That's the issue, I don't know $\phi$ but I do need to know what the derivative evaluates to when $\lambda = 0$

Comment: @GihaadHamman   When substituting $u=x+a\lambda$ at $\lambda=0$, you obtain: $$\begin{align}\left.\dfrac{\partial \phi(x+a\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}\right\rvert_{\lambda=0} &=\left.a\dfrac{\mathrm d \phi(u) }{\mathrm d u}\right\rvert_{u=x} \\ &=a~\phi'(x)\end{align}$$  You **cannot** evaluate it further unless you know what is $\phi$ (or at least its derivative).